# Building list of daily new user count in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to build a list of daily user signup counts. Below is how I am doing this, but is it the most logical way?

```
users = User.objects.all()
oldest_user_date = users.order_by('date_joined')[0].date_joined
day_difference = (datetime.now() - oldest_user_date).days

historical_user_signups_per_day = []
while day_difference > 0:
    days_user_signups = users.filter(date_joined__gt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=day_difference+1), date_joined__lt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=day_difference)).count()
    daily_count = {
        'count': days_user_signups,
        'date': datetime.now()-timedelta(days=day_difference)
    }
    historical_user_signups_per_day.append(daily_count)
    day_difference -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For a single day:

```
daily_users = User.objects.filter(date_joined__day=datetime.today().day).count()
```

For a range of days:

```
users = User.objects.all()
count_by_day = [{'count':users.filter(date_joined__day=x.day).count(), \
                 'date':x} \ 
                  for x in User.objects.dates('date_joined','days')]
```

Comment: This is great, but do you know how to make it also include dates where there are 0 users?

Comment: Actually, this isn't right, because it is just matching DAY (24) so it doesn't work over the period of many months

Comment: It goes through the list of days of your `date_joined` field, and it returns a `datetime` object, which has all the various parts of the date. To get it to be more precise, you can adjust the lookup. So do `__day=x.day,__month=x.month` for example.

Answer (score 0):

To find current day's new user count:

```
def get_curr_day_new_user_count():
     from datetime import date
     from django.contrib.auth.models import User

     today = date.today()
     return User.objects.filter(date_joined__contains=today).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I came across the same problem I researched in the Django documentation and found that the format of `date_joined` is `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"`. As you want all users from a single day and not from a single second, you can look if the `date_joined` contains the from the `datetime` library - I called it `reference_date` below.

```
oldest_user_date = User.objects.order_by('date_joined')[0].date_joined
day_difference = (datetime.now() - oldest_user_date).days
historical_user_signups_per_day = []

for i in range(day_difference):
    reference_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=i)
    historical_user_signups_per_day.append({
        'count': Users.objects.filter(date_joined__contains=reference_date).count(),
        'date': reference_date
    })
```

> This code works in the currently latest version of Django 3.0